# Sending AT commands to my internal UMTS modem

Tags: modem, at-command, umts

I have a thinkpad laptop and I would like to send AT commands to my modem once it is connected to the network. The interface that is used is '/dev/ttyACM0'. What is the best way to send my commands there? I tried gnokii but wasn't able to connect to my modem :/ I also tried echo'ing commands to the device, this worked, but it is not easy to get the output of the  command to proceed with the computation. Maybe one of you guys has a better way to do this. TIA

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried minicom?  (assuming from your interface that you are using Linux)

[Introduction to minicom.](http://www.question-defense.com/2010/07/27/use-minicom-for-linux-modem-dialup-at-command-testing)

Entering "minicom" in [www.alternativeto.net](http://www.alternativeto.net) gives a link to another terminal emulator for Linux called Cutecom, but I have no personal experience of it.